phpfilament label and andry side by side instead of stacked
All textentry have a layout like this
label
entry

But instead is it possible to do it like this:
label entry

As in, side by side.
I can find tons of information about putting sections side by side and using split, but not the simplest version, just the label and entry itself.
 Section::make('Datums')
     ->columnSpan(1)
     ->schema([
       TextEntry::make('apk_date')
           ->label('Apk Datum')
           ->badge()->color(function ($record) {
              $carbonApkDate = Carbon::parse($record->apk_date);
              if ($carbonApkDate->lt(now())) {
                 return 'red';
              } elseif ($carbonApkDate->lt(now()->addMonth())) {
                 return 'yellow';
              } else {
                 return 'green';
              }
         })
      ->columnSpan(2)
      ->date('d-m-Y'),
    TextEntry::make('end_date')
      ->label('End Date')
      ->color('primary'),
      // Add more TextEntries as needed
    ]),

Tried building it from grids or using split

Just use ->inlineLabel() in TextInput

Using Built-in Layouts (if supported)
Column Span and Grid Layouts:
If the library you’re using supports grid layouts or column spans, you can define how much space each element should take. Adjust the layout settings to place the label and entry side by side.
Example with Column Span:
Ensure the layout is set to display side by side by adjusting the column spans:
Section::make('Datums')
    ->columnSpan(1)
    ->schema([
        TextEntry::make('apk_date')
            ->label('Apk Datum')
            ->badge()->color(function ($record) {
                $carbonApkDate = Carbon::parse($record->apk_date);
                if ($carbonApkDate->lt(now())) {
                    return 'red';
                } elseif ($carbonApkDate->lt(now()->addMonth())) {
                    return 'yellow';
                } else {
                    return 'green';
                }
            })
            ->columnSpan(2) //Add this line
            ->date('d-m-Y'),
        TextEntry::make('end_date')
            ->label('End Date')
            ->color('primary')
            ->columnSpan(2), //Add this line
        // Add more TextEntries as needed
    ]),


That's exactly what i already had, except i only added it to the apk datum as a test
